# returning all elements of a select tag with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a select tag that looks like this:

```
<select name="TZSelector" id="TheTZSelector">
  <option>add another timezone</option>
  <option>------------------------------------------------------</option>
  <option></option>
  <option value="-8.00">(Pacific Time) San Francisco</option>
  <option value="-7.00">(Mountain Time) Denver
......
</select>
```

How can I return all the values that are in the options. Notice that option 1,2 and 3 don't have values but that all others do.
I'm looking for something like this:

```
$(...).each(function () { MyFunction takes the value of $(this) as parameter });
```

That way, I can write MyFunction and iterate through the collection of options.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will select all option's that have values;

```
$('select > option[value]').each(function() {
  // Your magic here
  // $(this).val() is the value of the option
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/8PHDp/1/

Comment: Should it be $('#TheTZSelector > option[value]').each(function() {
  alert($(this));
}); It's showing [Object] [Object]

Comment: Yes sure, for your HTML that would be perfect! Two objects is what it should show as there are two values, san fransisco and denver.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_opt_vals($select){
    var all_val = [];
    $('option', $select).each(function(index, item){
        all_val.push(item.value);
    })
    return all_val;
}

//call like this:
var opt_array = get_opt_vals($('#TheTZSelector'));

console.log(opt_array);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/yqxX4/